# NetMulticast | Not beeing called in client

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

My problem is that a function with "NetMulticast" is not beeing called on clients.

I have a function like this:

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, NetMulticast, Reliable, Category = "Construct")
void Build(...);
```

Which i call from my 'GameModeBase'. It is executed on the server, but not on the clients.
The function belongs to a component of an actor.
Both the component and actor are beeing replicated (I see their constructors beeing called on the client).
'
Build' is called in PostInitializeComponents of the 'GameModeBase', right after creation of actor and the component.

Is there something I am clearly doing wrong, or something i might have not done that is required?
What can i do to find out the issue?

I'am printing the relevant event, the actor is "Terrain", and its component "TerrainMesh".
Maybe the problem is that the terrain does not exist yet on the client when I try to call build?
That would seem like very undesired behaviour of the replication system though...

```
LogTemp: GameModeBase | Constructor
LogTemp: Terrain | Constructor SERVER
LogTemp: TerrainMesh | Constructor SERVER
LogTemp: TerrainMesh | Build SERVER <---- The replicated function not beeing replicated.
LogTemp: Terrain | Constructor CLIENT
LogTemp: TerrainMesh | Constructor CLIENT
```

---

EDIT:

To make it simpler, i put the function in the actor itself. If i represent the code as blueprint it clearly states it should replicate to all, but it does not.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/o78i9]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, you cannot pass references to USTRUCT classes.

Comment: You are the hero that people need, but don't deserve. The one that posts answers to his own questions once he finds them.